# Are you aware of new blog posts?

Tags: support, blog

Maybe it's just me, but I miss the blog posts when they are published. The latest blog post was 9 days ago...

How are new blog posts promoted? I thought they should be in the 'Community Bulletin' but does that exist in Cooking?

Here's a link to [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136419/how-can-we-improve-the-visibility-of-new-blog-posts) about it on MSO (where I'm GUI Junkie).

Comment: You can avoid missing new blog posts by subscribing to the RSS feed ;)

Comment: We'd like to do something about it; please add suggestions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140556/the-community-bulletin-is-not-good-enough-for-promoting-community-blog-posts

Comment: @derobert, LOL, I saw you and rumtscho with <1k rep, but didn't notice it was MSO :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are automatically promoted on the community bulletin. I don't know what the promotion duration is.

We currently publish every second Wednesday, with a few holiday specials in between. We would like to move to a weekly schedule, but don't yet have enough contributions.

The blog has a RSS feed too, if you want to be sure to not miss anything. I personally don't use RSS for pages which update so rarely.

Sadly, there is no possibility other than the not very visible community bulletin to promote new posts to the community.

Comment: Thanks, that means I've just missed all these bulletins.

Comment: I think they are up for a short time only, maybe 2 days

Comment: Really? I think RSS is most useful for stuff that updates rarely.

Comment: This has been a problem on SE for a while - subsidiary content like blogs is way, way underexposed.